# jetstream laravel login dose not check my database and bring me back to login page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

jetstream laravel login dose not check my database and bring me back to same login page !!

I want after login the system go to redirects route
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNDyb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q7Dj.png)

Comment: I also use this 

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = 'redirects';

Comment: I recommend first reading the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and use code blocks not images.

Answer (score 0):

if i assume what you trying to do correctly, you want the logic to be run before the destination is reached after login/registration. Thats what i gather from your images. PS when you using code, dont take a picture. click the curly brackets in the text area and write your code there.

In your RouteServiceProvider which is in your providers directory in the App folder,
change the following line to this:

```
public const HOME = 'redirect';
```

in your routing add this. Change the controller to whatever controller you are using but this is the code:

```
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/redirect', [App\Http\Controllers\User::class, 'redirect'])->name('redirect');
});
```

i wrap mine in the authentication grouping but you can do as you like..

This will look for the redirect function that is in the picture you provided. Again because the way the question was asked, i can only answer on what i assume you want to do...